# Is it possible to bind a Spring form to two different model attributes?

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible to bind a Spring form to two different model attributes?
Something like: `<form:form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST" commandName="modelA, modelB">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. You have to define another modelC which holds modelA and modelB as its member